# Pandas `to_sql` gives `Table already exists` error with `if_exists = 'append'`

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm trying to write to a MySQL database with Pandas (v1.3.4), SQLAlchemy (v1.4.26), and PyMySQL (v1.0.2). I can create a new table (called 'test_table') using the pandas `to_sql` method, but subsequent attempts to write to the same table gives:

```py
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'test_table' already exists")
```

I've done this previously in SQLite, so I'm not sure why it's not working in MySQL. Is this a problem with my syntax, or is there something that might need to be changed in the database server configuration?

Here's the code I'm using.

First, import and establish a connection to the database server:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

sqlEngine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@127.0.0.1', pool_recycle=3600)
con  = sqlEngine.connect()
```

Establish the specific database name:

```py
sql = '''
USE my_database
'''
con.execute(sql);
```

Generate an entry and write to a new table called `test_table`:

```
entry = pd.DataFrame({
    'PersonID': 0,
    'LastName': 'smith',
    'FirstName': 'joe',
}, index=[0])
entry.to_sql('test_table', con, if_exists='append')
```

Verify that my entry made it into the table:

```py
sql = '''
SELECT *
FROM test_table
'''
pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
```

which gives:

[image]

So far, so good. Now I try to add a new entry my `test_table` table, using the `if_exists='append'` argument so that the new entry will be appended to the end of my existing table:

```
entry = pd.DataFrame({
    'PersonID': 1,
    'LastName': 'smith',
    'FirstName': 'mary',
}, index=[0])
entry.to_sql('test_table', con, if_exists='append')
```

Which results in:

```py
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'test_table' already exists")
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    `index` BIGINT, 
    `PersonID` BIGINT, 
    `LastName` TEXT, 
    `FirstName` TEXT
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Why is Pandas trying to create a new table here? How can I force it to append to the existing table instead?

Comment: I should add, if I skip Pandas and add to the table directly, it works just fine: sql = '''
    INSERT INTO test_table (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
    VALUES (1, 'smith', 'mary');
'''
con.execute(sql)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/E6M5tUGh) works fine for me using the same versions of the components that you are using. There must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: It may be a problem with capitalization on the table name.  I have found that trying to use **to_sql**  to append data into an SQLite database table using Python's built-in sqlite3 returns this error when there is a difference in capitalization between the sqlite file and name I give in my **to_sql** command

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I found two ways to solve it although I lack the insight as to why this solves it:

1. Either pass the database name in the url when creating a connection
2. or pass the database name as a schema in `pd.to_sql`.

Doing both does not hurt.

````
```
#create connection to MySQL DB via sqlalchemy & pymysql
user = credentials['user']
password = credentials['password']
port = credentials['port']
host = credentials['hostname']
dialect = 'mysql'
driver = 'pymysql'
db_name = 'test_db'

# setup SQLAlchemy   
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
cnx = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/' 
engine = create_engine(cnx) 

# create database
with engine.begin() as con:
    con.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")

############################################################
# either pass the db_name  vvvv - HERE- vvvv after creating a database
cnx = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}'      
############################################################
engine = create_engine(cnx) 

table = 'test_table'
col = 'test_col'
with engine.begin() as con:
    # this would work here instead of creating a new engine with a new link
    # con.execute(f"USE {db_name}")
    con.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {table} ({col} CHAR(1));")

# insert into database
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({col : ['a','b','c']})

with engine.begin() as con:
    # this has no effect here
    # con.execute(f"USE {db_name}")
    df.to_sql(
        name= table,
        if_exists='append',
        con=con, 
############################################################
# or pass it as a schema vvvv - HERE - vvvv
        #schema=db_name,
############################################################
        index=False
    )```
````

Tested with python version `3.8.13`, sqlalchemy `1.4.32` and pandas `1.4.2`.
Same problem might have appeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985162/sql-alchemy-pymssql-pandas-0-24-2-to-sql-trying-to-create-table-when-table-alr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765863/python-pandas-to-sql-append).